# Using GTM: How to Simultaneously Fetch both Values from The Key Called 'id' in dataLayer?

Tags: arrays, google-tag-manager

In my EEC implementation, I need to fetch both the ids from the array in the dataLayer below and insert them to another pixel. This pixel accepts array but i'm not sure how to proceed.

```
},          
products:[
{
    name: 'haranger', 
    id:'123'
},
{
    name: 'haranger', 
    id:'456'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One would be to first load the products array into a datalayer variable - presumably this is nested into your e-commerce-object, so this might be something like `ecommerce.products` (depends on your datalayer).

Then you can create a custom javascript variable that extracts the ids from the dataLayer variable and puts them into an array. A custom javascript variable is a anonymous function that return a value, so it might look like this:

```
function() {
    var array_of_ids = [];
    products = {{dataLayer_variable_with_products}};
    products.forEach(function(item) {
       array_of_ids.push(item.id)
    });
    return array_of_ids;
}
```

(Some very old browsers do not support forEach on arrays, so you might want to use a simple loop instead).

Your "products" are an array of objects, so every iteration of foreach/loop gives you an individual object and you can address its properties via the dot notation (`object.name`, `object.id`). You then put the value for the desired property onto an array, and once you iterated through all of the products array you return the array with your results.